# Setting nodes within a networkx graph as infected and uninfected

Tags: python, networkx, infection

I have the karate club graph, I wish to determine a few random nodes within there as infected nodes, while the rest are uninfected. I tried to use:

```
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
#pos = nx.spectral_layout(G)
bb = tuple(nx.betweenness_centrality(G))
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'betweenness', bb)
G.nodes[1]['betweenness']
```

As an example to see if it can work. Though it returns a key error for 'betweenness' in the final line. What ways are there to manually or randomly select a few nodes in the graph, and give them a 1 for infected while the the rest are 0. Or is there a better way to set infections within this graph?

Comment: May be worth looking at [EoN](https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - disclaimer I wrote it.

Comment: Can you say more about what you are going to do with this?  There are lots of ways you can do it.  You can create a list of infected nodes at each time.  You can simply assign each node an attribute giving its status, etc.

Answer (score 1):

just follow the correct function call for [set_node_attributes](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html)

**Correct syntax:**

```
set_node_attributes(G, values, name=None)
```

so your variable **bb** will come before name **betweenness**

**code:**

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
bb = tuple(nx.betweenness_centrality(G))
# changed
nx.set_node_attributes(G,  bb, 'betweenness')
print(G.nodes[1])
```

**Result:**

[image]

*Also if you remove the tuple part, you will get score output:*

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
bb = tuple(nx.betweenness_centrality(G))
# changed
bb = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
nx.set_node_attributes(G,  bb, 'betweenness')
print(G.nodes[1])
```

**Result:**

[image]